# How can I optimize my syntax highlighting in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, syntax-highlighting

Hello guys I am working in a text editor in android and I want to optimize my text editor. When my text editor is have a 100 lines of code it becomes laggy
Here is my implementation code:

```
private void onEditorListener() {
    edtEditor.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            _lastTypeTime = new Date();
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
            last_text_edit = System.currentTimeMillis();
            handler.postDelayed(runnable, idle_min);
            runnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= (last_text_edit + idle_min - 500)) {
                            // user hasn't changed the EditText for longer than
                            // the min delay (with half second buffer window)
                            textHighLighter(s);  // your queries
                            if (!already_queried) { // don't do this stuff twice.
                                already_queried = true;
                                //textHighLighter(s);  // your queries
                            }
                        }
                        //already_queried = false;
                        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: how about reducing delay time: `(last_text_edit + idle_min - 500)`

Comment: improved code formating

Comment: @Anirudha Agashe any suggestion how can I improved code formatting

Comment: @dkb When I reduced the delayed time its become to laggy

Comment: @VincentLlauderes Just make sure there no unnecessary blank lines and the code is indendented properly. Even I have done a poor job of editing it will rectify it now.

Comment: @VincentLlauderes have you ever checked how long does your method `textHighLigher()` run?

Comment: My method in textHighLighter() is around 20+ lines of code

Answer (score 0):

try this.

add `private boolean blocks = false;` at field variable.

```
private void onEditorListener() {
    edtEditor.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
            if (blocks) {
                return;
            }
            blocks = true;
            textHighLighter(s);  // your queries
            blocks = false;
        }
}
```